# Which is faster '1GB RAM with 64 bit' or '2GB RAM with 32 bit'

Tags: ram, processor

I planed to purchase new mobile. I confused with processor and RAM.

1. Quad-core 1.2 GHz Cortex-A53 (64 Bit) 1GB RAM
2. Quad-core 1.6 GHz Cortex-A7 (32 Bit) 2GB RAM

Which one will be faster?

Comment: The second one has more RAM and a faster processor (and a newer model one too). The 32/64 bit isn't really a factor IMHO in the decision. If a device had over 4Gb of RAM then a 64 bit version may be useful, but only in certain circumstances. Since Android is Linux it's really even less of a concern again. A full answer to this would be far too long, and broad for this site. The second one is better, but there is a degree of opinion in that too.

Comment: Given the size of RAM you are talking about here, 32-bit 2Gb would potentially lead to better performance assuming a well set up and tuned operating system is installed on it. The advantages of 64-bit are that it can handle more computational values in memory, but if you have less memory to work with your advantage is diminished. Also bear in mind that if an application is not designed to take advantage of the 64-bit architecture then the whole arguement is moot as it would still behave in a 32-bit manner, once again in this instance more RAM would prove more advantageous.